# Add a header row using spark sql syntax to the top of the table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large table (several TBs) that I am doing an extract on using Spark and want to add headers in the output. I am restricted (internal constraints) to only using Spark SQL syntax (ie no java/scala/python syntax can be used). I am wondering if there is a cheap way to add headers in the output. I have looked into using UNION ALL and while it does work, it doesn't guarantee order which means that when reading the extract, I'd have to do a .filter.first operation instead of just a .first. Since this is a large extract, it'd mean 30+ minutes spent doing .filter.first.

Option 1 (works fine but reading of output is slow):

```
select "colA", "colB" union all 
select colA, colB from table1
```

Another option I have tried is adding a sort order when writing the extract (on top of UNION ALL) and then adding an ORDER BY clause. However, that causes a massive shuffle and leads to scaling issues.

Option 2 (doesn't work with large datasets due to shuffles):

```
select colA, colB from (
select "0" as sort_order, "colA" as colA, "colB" as colB union all
select "1", colA, colB from table 1 
) order by sort_order
```

Wondering if there's a cheaper way to add header rows. Would appreciate any help here.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds wrong for so many reasons... Why would you try to do this in the first place?

Comment: curious to know why it sounds wrong.

Comment: if the concern is around adding headers, that seems like a fairly standard practice across the industry for TSV data. 


If on the other hand, the concern is around options explored so far, I did raise the question here :)

Comment: To shed some light on my motivations though, there's a separate spark system where I am reading the output of the data above using Scala. I want to avoid using integer indexing to read TSV data as that can be error prone. Ex: 0 may mean colA today, but if someone modifies the sql query, then it can be colB tomorrow. Seems like a fragile way of doing things. Using headers, I can map column names to integer indices in code, thus making it robust to such scenarios

Comment: (1) Why TSV and not Parquet? (2) Do you really need a query for extraction? Why not copy the source files?

Comment: (1) system constraints (doesn't support Parquet yet) and (2) Need to select only relevant columns and not the entire thing (which is gonna be even more massive)

Comment: The scenario is still not clear. Who is running the query? What do you do with the results?  BTW, the "internal constraints" mentioned on your post, is usually indication that the task is being handled by the wrong team in the organization.

Answer (score 0):

- Spark, SQL syntax, as you asked
- Each file will be created with an header

---

```
create table mydb.mytable
using csv
options(sep='\t', header=true, path = '...')
as
select ... from ...
```